# Performing calculations based on header names in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, sum

I try to sum up the commission and revenue in a Google Sheet but since the columns in the dataset can sometimes change positions due to added columns I want to perform calculations based on **header name**.

I already got this formula to work to get the sum of the column where the header name is "commission". However, now I want to get the total commission from the commission column when the status (in the status column) is "open" (see the image)

The formula I use at the moment to get the sum of the column with the header name "commission" is: =SUM(FILTER($A$5:$Z, $A$4:$Z$4  = "commission")).

So in this example (image) the total commission would be: 7 euros

Hope someone can help. Thanks!

[image: Example table in Google Sheets]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=sum(ifna(filter(filter(A5:Z,A4:Z4="commission"),filter(A5:Z,A4:Z4="status")="open")))
```

[image]